# Есть ли свойство для получения максимально возможного значения прокрутки без учёта ползунка?

Tags: javascript

Я придумал прокручивать страницу до конца и возвращать `scrollHeight`, а затем прокручивать страницу обратно, в начало. Есть ли какой-то нативный метод?

```js
document.body.style.height = '3000px'
let max_scroll_value = getMaxScrollValue()
console.log(max_scroll_value)

function getMaxScrollValue() {
  scroll(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
  setTimeout(() => scroll(0, 0), 0)
  return scrollY
}
```

Comment: эм, `scrollHeight - window.innerHeight`? или что-то подобное: из общей высоты вычитаем высоту окна - получается максимальное значение к которому может быть прокручено

Comment: О боги... я почему то думал что недостающие пиксели это размер ползунка. фэйспалм.

Comment: скорее всего это были `margin`

Comment: @Grundy не, я именно думал что прокрутив до конца, вот эта недостающая разница между `max_scroll_value` и `3000px` это высота ползунка... хз почему )

Comment: не, тогда какой-то большой ползунок получается :-) хотя формально - это значение должно соответствовать высоте вертикального скролла :) именно самой полосы прокрутки